# How to call winapi function via pointer to this function?

Tags: c++, call, dllimport, dllexport

I get functions from `ntdll.dll` dynamically, using `GetProcAddress` winapi function like this:

```
HMODULE ntdllh = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
unsigned char* ptrToNtLoadDriver 
                        = (unsigned char*)GetProcAddress(ntdllh, "NtLoadDriver");
```

How can I call `NtLoadDriver` function via `ptrToNtLoadDriver` ? I thought of something like this: `((NTSTATUS NtLoadDriver(PUNICODE_STRING driverServiceName))ptrToNtLoadDriver)(fooString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. do typedef "X" for function type you want to call (example: "typedef returntype (*X)(argtype);")
2. change "unsigned char* ptrToNtLoadDriver" to "X ptrToNtLoadDriver"
3. call function as "ptrToNtLoadDriver(argsHere)"

Answer (score 0):

((NTSTATUS (WINAPI*)(PUNICODE_STRING))ptrToNtLoadDriver)(fooStrin);